# Java console: readPassord()- size/length of the password

Tags: java-7

Am trying to understand java console class and it's readPassword method. Following is the code i have,

```
package com.files; 
import java.io.Console; 
public class NewConsole {   
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console c = System.console(); 
        char[] pw=new char[2];
        pw = c.readPassword("%s", "pw: ");
        System.out.println(pw);     
}
}
```

pw is char array of size 2. But when executing the above program if i enter pw as  "abcd" in cmd(> than the array size of pw) it works fine. Why is it not throwing index out bound of exception as the size of input exceeds the size of pw?.

Comment: `pw` no longer *is char array of size 2*, you reassign `pw`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

watch below code that you can figure out whats going on here you are assigning new char sequence to `pw[]`

```
import java.io.Console;
public class NewConsole {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Console c = System.console();
    char[] pw=new char[2];
    char [] nw = "hello".toCharArray();
    System.out.println(pw.length);
    pw = nw;
    System.out.println(pw.length);
}
}
```

and also if you want to throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException then try

```
import java.io.Console;
public class NewConsole {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Console c = System.console();
    char[] pw=new char[2];
    char [] str = c.readPassword("%s", "pw: ");
    for(int i=0;i<str.length;i++)
    pw [i] = str[i];
    System.out.println(pw);
}
}
```

;-) if you find whats going on then please close question